# Python: How to check if network port 22 is open from a file containing IP addresses

Tags: python, port

please help. I guess a need to loop through the file somehow?

```
import socket
for line in open('hosts.t'):
    print line,
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
result = sock.connect_ex((line,22))
if result == 0:
  print 'port OPEN'
else:
  print 'port CLOSED'
```

Comment: Post a sample of `hosts.t`

Comment: cat hosts.t
10.x.x.x
10.x.x.x
10.x.x.x

Comment: what's `print line,`? why are you establishing connection for the last line in the file and not for each of the lines inside the `for` loop?

Comment: lol, I don't know what I'm doing. Can you help me please.